# NSURLConnection Delegates Issue

Tags: objective-c, delegates, nsurlconnection

I have a problem with NSURLConnection delegate. Simply I need to get a result from the server based on that result, I will do some stuff.
The problem is :

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

Method is calling at last and I am receiving answer in this part. Then I cannot use the result that came from the server.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DidfinishLaunch started");
    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

    if (!self.parsedJsonContent) {
        self.parsedJsonContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<self.json.count; i++) {
    NSString *result = [self.json objectAtIndex:i];
    self.user.result = result;}
    }
}
```

and when I want to use the value of result in MainViewController:

```
NSLog(@"result: %@",[self.jsonProcess GetJsonResultForLogin]);
```

it comes empty. So how am I going to grab the value of result, couse the value of result is filling in connectionDidFinishLoading which is the last method that called.

Comment: There's either a problem with how you're building the `responseData` in `didReceiveData` or the response you're receiving from the server is not valid JSON. If the JSON conversion returns `nil`, `NSLog(@"responseData: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:self.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);` and see what the `responseData` contains.

Comment: Debugging 101: Break the problem down into basic statements. Debug or log the values. Inspect.  IN this case `NSLog("responseData: %@", self.responseData);` and examine what you got back from the server.

Comment: There is no problem with result, it is coming as "record exist" but didFinishLoading method executes at last,meanwhile all other methods in the mainViewcontroller class are finished. so how am i going to send back result to mainViewControllar class and do what i want.

Comment: What is [self.jsonProcess GetJsonResultForLogin] doing? Is that initiating the download?

Comment: @AhmetNM If you're concerned about the fact that `didReceiveData` finishes asynchronously, you can just put code inside `connectionDidFinishLoading` that initiates the update of the view controller (e.g. if it was a table view controller, call `[self.tableView reloadData]`).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to grab the data received in:

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
```

and just use the

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

to know when the connection ends.

Comment: The thing is: First i am checking whether record exist or not from the server.
1. I Requested from server
2. Then I wanted to see the result, I printed out.
3. then all delegates executed.
in this case how can i catch the value of result. when the result came, compiler already executes my 
NSLog(@"result: %@",[self.jsonProcess GetJsonResultForLogin]); line...

Comment: I do not understand why 2 and 3 are different stages. To see any result the delegate methods have to have been called. Are you using MainViewController as delegate for NSURLConnection?

Answer (score 0):

SPJsonProcess.m

```
-(void)OpenAConnection:(NSString *)URL appendStringURL:(NSString *)appendURL
{

   NSMutableString *postUrl = [NSMutableString stringWithString:URL];

if (![appendURL isEqualToString:nil]) {
        [postUrl appendString:appendURL];
    }

NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:postUrl];

   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl];

   self.responseData = [NSMutableData data];

   NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:jsonUrl];

   connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc]initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];

   [connection scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

   [connection start];


-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{

    NSLog(@"DidfinishLaunch started");

    self.json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:self.responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableLeaves error:nil];

   if (!self.parsedJsonContent) {

       self.parsedJsonContent = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }

for (int i=0;i < self.json.count; i++) {

NSString *result = [self.json objectAtIndex:i];

self.user.result = result;
}
}

-(NSString *)GetJsonResultForLogin
{

   return self.user.result;
}
```

LOGIN VIEW CONTROLLER

```
>-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user
{
>[self.jsonProcess OpenAConnection:@"My Domain adress" appendStringURL:appendString];

>NSLog(@"Method invoked");


>NSLog(@"result: %@",[self.jsonProcess GetJsonResultForLogin]);
```

result as a log comes null. But in didFinishLoading method gets result from server without a problem.